# Selenium Web Driver issue in Threading. C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium

Here's the code.

```
browser = new FirefoxDriver();
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
browser.FindElement(By.Name("ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown")).SendKeys("asdf");
```

It works ok but if I run in thread it shows element not visible.... why it's throwing in a thread?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you men by `if I run in thread it shows element not visible`? Any specific configuration for `Thread`?

Comment: I am running a thread in which I am navigating a URL and then access the element. When I try to access element it say "element is not visible". But If I run the code without thread, It works fine.

Comment: How do you run it without a thread???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Element could be non-visible cuz page didnt reload at check moment or website using dynamic names, classes etc.

You can try something like this:

```
IWebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry");

while ( true ) {
    try {
        browser.FindElement(By.Name("ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown")).SendKeys("asdf"); 
        break;
    }
    catch { Thread.Sleep(1000);}
}
```

Comment: not working bro. I told you that my code working fine without thread but in thread it showing exception

Comment: You can try to use Task for it, mb it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the `xpath` you tried out, it seems the `name` attribute is dynamic. To locate the text box for **`Registration number`** You can try either of the following options :

- **`CssSelector`** :

  ```
  browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[class=text text xlong v_registrationNumber v_required][id^=ph_pagebody_)]")).SendKeys("asdf");
  ```
- **`XPath`** :

  ```
  browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='text text xlong v_registrationNumber v_required'][starts-with(@id, 'ph_pagebody_')]")).SendKeys("asdf");
  ```

Comment: not working bro. I told you that my code working fine without thread but in thread it showing exception –

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Do you see any error? What does the error says? Can you update the question with error stack trace?

Comment: this line 

"browser.FindElement(By.Name("ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown")).SendKeys("asdf")" is working fine and returning the element. But When I run this code in a thread it doesn't find the element.

Comment: @user1448783 Did you give a try to my Answer? Can you update me the result?